# No tab bar in one child view since Xcode 9.2 update

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

Since I updated to Xcode 9.2, the tab bar isn't displayed anymore in one of my child views and I'm struggling to get it back.

I did everything using the storyboard.
Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

As you can see, the same segue is used in both views but the result is not the same...

Comment: Have you tried going to Storyboard -> View Controller Attributes Inspector -> Bottom Bar -> Inferred?

Comment: Yes, the bottom bar is inferred in every view

Comment: I can see singe-single tab bar icon below every child vc

Comment: If you look closely you can see that view controller on the right has no bottom bar compared to the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a small workaround. Maybe it is the right way to do it and my first implementation was wrong.

So instead of embedding the tab bar controller in a nav bar controller I ended up putting each tab in a nav bar controller.
Like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwdv2.png)

And now everything is working correctly.